Amazon Product Links Scraping Using BeautifulSoup and Request
I am scraping this Amazon page:
https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mercedes&crid=37ZCGOIJ0A8V4&sprefix=me%2Caps%2C1587&ref=nb_sb_noss_2
Here's my code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
URL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mercedes&crid=37ZCGOIJ0A8V4&sprefix=me%2Caps%2C1587&ref=nb_sb_noss_2"
HEADER = ({'User-Agent':'', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})
r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADER)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

aTag = soup.find_all("a")
print(aTag)

I even mentioned my right user agent but still it returns status code 503. But when I replace URL with https://amazon.com/ it returns status 200.
I expected the status code to be 200. Even after trying everything it still doesn't work.

Amazon doesn't like being scraped. You could try the undetected_chromedriver module (install from PyPI)

I tried using the URL you provided but every second time it gave me an error page saying "Sorry! Something went wrong on our end." I would suggest changing URL to something like this, with no additional parameters and insert a User-Agent like the one in the code below.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=mercedes"
HEADER = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

r = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADER)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

aTag = soup.find_all("a")
print(aTag)

